# anyway to access pipeline global variable in email-ext template

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

As build ENV can be accessed in email-ext template, is there anyway to access pipeline global variable in email-ext template.

We have parent pipeline trigger 10 sub pipeline jobs in parallel, we need format each sub job's build status by ourselves. Currently we formatted all the data into one global map we have in parent pipeline, would like to use that global map in email-ext template to format the email output.

one way is we format all the data in file, then use script to format the file before email-ext template processing, but that is little complex.

so we would like to know if any other good option for such req, but did not get any hint on google.

Adding our own build ENV is not option, as we need format the data in parent pipleline.

thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the emailext in the main Pipeline where the map is created, then why not just pass the map details in the subject section of your email like so:

```
   emailext (
        subject: "STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'",
        body: """<p>STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
            <p>Build Status of job1:;'${MyMap.get(JOB1)}' </p> <br/>
            <p>Build Status of job2:;'${MyMap.get(JOB2)}' </p> <br/>
            .......
             """,
        recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
    )
```

also try MyMap.JOB1 directly,
You may have to do some trial and error to get it to work properly. But as you can see in the example env.JOB_NAME is actually a Map with key and value data.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks Thomas for your suggestion. Yes, this way should work. we use one email template to process email content right now, so did not think about processing in pipeline directly. thanks again.

Comment: If it worked then can you select it as the right answer so that others who face this issue will know what to do :)

Comment: i still have no permission to vote now, will mark this after gaining 15 points.